# MySql will not import mysql dump

Tags: sql, mysql

mysqldump v 5.10 
Dumped entire database into a single .sql file. 
Completely removed mysql installation, and reinstalled fresh. 
Import Data > dumpedfile.sql 
Fails with syntax error every time at same line.

```
DELIMITER ;; 
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `AddDate` BEFORE INSERT ON interviewlist FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.InterviewListDateCreated = CURDATE(); */;; 
DELIMITER ;
```

Always fails when it tries to create the trigger/event/ or procedure. I have multiple triggers defined for most tables. So having to recreate them one by one would be a bit annoying. Did mysqldump put in the wrong syntax? 
I am trying to import as root user through MySql Workbench > import data

EDIT: Removing that block of code allowed all of the other triggers to insert properly... odd since the syntax is the exact same on all of them.
Also, redumping the file using "Add Locks/Unlocks" option in mysqldump allows the file to import perfectly. *Shrug*

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Error code 1 Line 59:- Syntax Error Check MySQL documentation for proper syntax to use near /*...
The above excerpt is line 58,59,60 respectively